# Firebase realtime database transaction maxretry error with a particular decimal number 63.99999999999999

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database transaction to update a node.

See the following code:

```js
const addVal = 3.74;
return admin.database().ref(`admin/test/node`).transaction((current_value) => {
    return (current_value || 0) + addVal;
});
```

It works fine generally. But this gives `maxrety` 1-2 error randomly in a week (Not sure about the reason, may be due to high contention?).

But this time there is a particular problem when the node value is particular decimal values, it starts giving `maxrety` errors everytime.

In the above case, when **`current_value = 63.99999999999999`** existing in the node, the transactions never succeed. It throws the following error everytime:

`current_value = 62.99999999999999` or `64.99999999999999` or `64` works fine.

```js
Error: maxretry
    at Repo.rerunTransactionQueue_ (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14629:67)
    at Repo.rerunTransactions_ (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14534:10)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14513:19
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11946:17
    at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11976:17)
    at Connection.onDataMessage_ (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11290:14)
    at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11284:18)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11185:27)
    at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10773:18)
    at WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10824:22)
```

Note: The node is not being written by other clients. This is for testing.

Comment: Github issue response: "Thanks for reporting. You are likely hitting an issue with rounding errors either in the Node client, in the JSON transmission or on the backend. Our transaction code is however quite gnarly, and attempts to fix these errors in the past have caused regressions. I will keep this issue in mind for when we do overhaul this part of the codebase, but I would suggest to find a workaround on your end in the interim." https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/779